# Is it possible to populate array with user input in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

I am trying following but getting error "variable arr of type Array[Int] does not take type parameters."

```
object try_arr
{
  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    var arr = new Array[Int](3)
        for(i<- 1 to 3)
        {
          val num = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
          arr[i] = num
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

As already pointed out by Simon, you're trying to apply java syntax to scala code -- in scala [ ] are used to specify type and in order to access array elements you're shall use (), e.g. `xs(3)`

I guess the cleanest way to solve this is to make use of Array.fill method:

```
object FillTheArray {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val userInput = Array.fill(3) {
      scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In scala you index the array like this

```
arr(i) = num
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below statement

```
a(i)= scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

More of a side note, consider this more Scalish approach with immutable objects,

```
val xs = for (i <- 1 to 3; num = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()) yield num
```

where each value in the range (`1 to 3`) is *mapped* onto a user input. The resulting vector (`xs`) may be converted to an array,

```
xs.toArray
```

Likewise

```
(1 to 3).map(_ => scala.io.StdIn.readInt()).toArray
```

proves terser a code.

This is in contrast with the more imperative approach to creating a mutable array, and updating each position (referred by each value in the range) with a user input.

Answer (score 0):

in for loop can't 1 to 3 because array index start in 0 and beetween 0 to 2. Else shows error ArrayOutOfBound Exception.

Code : 
var arr = new ArrayInt

```
    for(i<- 0 to 2)
    {
        print("Enter number")
        val num = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
        arr(i) = num
    }
    arr.foreach((element:Int)=> print(element + " "))
```